# "PrimaryGeneratedColumn" NOT NULL constraint error

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am getting a null constraint error when saving an entity.

```
export abstract class BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
    createOn: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
    updatedOn: Date;

    @DeleteDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
    deletedOn: Date;
}
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."mytable" (
    "id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(), 
    "name" character varying(256) NOT NULL,     
    "createOn" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    "updatedOn" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    "deletedOn" TIMESTAMP, "rawData" text NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT "PK_a94b1ebd989b0e66e32761c1401" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
 )
```

When I insert a new item in nestjs I get:

```
{
   "statusCode": 400,
   "message": [
      "id must be a UUID"
   ],
   "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

When I insert a record using the db client it autogenerates the value.

I have seen the other post and it does not help me. It is for an older version of typeorm.

Why is TypeOrm enforcing the constraint even though it is not supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the class validator. Added @IsOptional

```
export class MyInDTO implements Readonly<MyDTO> {
  @ApiProperty({ required: true })
  @IsUUID()
  @IsOptional()
  id: string;
```